# calling asmx method in ASP.Net ASYNCHRONOUSLY?

Tags: asp.net, asmx

- I have an asmx web service  that is part of my ASP.Net web application. I would like to use event-based approach of calling this web service in an async manner. Is this possible and if so how? If this is not possible, what are the alternatives?
- Also, can I call in an async manner a static PageMethod in an aspx page that is decorated with '[WebMethod]' attribute? An example of  page method I have is:

  ```
      [WebMethod]
  public static SupplierData GetAgeSummary(string supplierId)
  {
      return ABC.Data.SupplierData.GetAgeSummary(supplierId);
  }
  ```

By async I mean async in server-side and not on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side of a website can't be called asynchronously in a reliable fashion. Since all threads are only alive for the duration of the parent thread, if your asynchronous thread is still executing when the site finishes and moves on to the response, this will terminate the parent thread and all children will be forced to stop executing.

If the application you are using is a WinForms or WPF application using the web service as a reference then it can be called asynchronously because the application (which runs on the parent thread) can be relied upon to be alive for the duration of the service call. However, in a web application, it is too likely that the response will be constructed before the callback is delivered.